# Append and prepend to column in csv based on identical entries

Tags: python-3.x

I have a three-column CSV file containing about 200 lines (including whitelines) which looks like below. Now I want to add parenthesis around entries in the second column, based on identical entries in the third column.

**Note:** '_' underscore entries are not to be treated as possible 'identical entry'.
**Note2:** identical entries (third column) can be one or more

```
1   _   _
2   A   A1
3   B   A1
4   C   A4
5   _   _

6   A   A5
7   B   A5
8   _   _
9   C   A4
10  D   A4
11  E   A4

12  E   A2

# pseudocode:
IF there are multiple identical N entries in the third column:
    then -> add left parenthesis to first entry second column
            add right parenthesis to last entry second column

IF there is ONE entry in the third column:
    then -> add parenthesis around entry in second column
```

Output that i am looking for:

```
1   _   _
2   (A  A1
3   B)  A1
4   (C) A4
5   _   _

6   (A  A5
7   B)  A5
8   _   _
9   (C  A4
10  D   A4
11  E)  A4

12  (E) A2
```

Edit, trying to explain in more detail:

I am reading column2 and column3 into two arrays.

```
for i, j in enumerate(column3):
   if j == identical consecutive entries column3:
       # get indexes of those entries
       # add ( to first corresponding index column2
       # add ) to last corresponding index column2
       # index could be one entry, or a range of entries
```

Comment: *ignore '_' underscore entries* means that the script should ignore underscores, or that readers of this question should ignore underscores?

Comment: The script, edited in question, thanks.